# 2 button groups buttons not selected independantly

Tags: visualforce, lightning

I've got 2 button groups that are rendered via `<apex:repeat>`. First apex:repeat renders groups of buttons - 'Sex' and 'Age'. Second renders buttons themselves - 'M', 'russianSymbol', '18-25', '25-30', '30-40'. I wrapped second `<apex:repeat>` into

```
<div class="slds-button-group" role="group">
```

and thought that I'll have 2 independant groups of buttons and selection of it will act Independantly.

For now if I select 'M' and then select '18-25' - the 'M' will be deselected and '18-25' will be selected. What I need is when I select 'M' and then select '18-25', the selection of 'M' would not disappear.

```
<panel>
    <apex:repeat value="{!wraps}" var="w"> 
        <div class="slds-container--center slds-container--small slds-align--absolute-center">
            <apex:outputText value="{!w.fieldLabel}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-container--center slds-container--small slds-align--absolute-center">
            <div class="slds-button-group" role="group">
                <apex:repeat value="{!w.values}" var="wv"> 

                    <panel class="slds-align--absolute-center slds-p-around--medium">
                        <apex:commandButton styleclass="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-not-selected" value="{!wv}" rerender="hiddenBlock" action="{!setValues}">
                            <apex:param name="nameField" value="{!w.fieldName}" assignTo="{!nameField}"/>
                            <apex:param name="valueField" value="{!wv}" assignTo="{!valueField}"/>
                        </apex:commandButton>
                    </panel>

                </apex:repeat>
            </div>
        </div>
    </apex:repeat>
</panel>
<apex:pageBlock id="hiddenBlock" rendered="false"></apex:pageBlock>
```

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

**Updated:**
Controller:

```
public with sharing class CreateInfoContactController {

private final InfoContact__c infoContact;

public List<Wrapper> wraps {get; set;}

public String nameField {get;set;}
public String valueField {get;set;}

// The extension constructor initializes the private member
// variable mysObject by using the getRecord method from the standard
// controller.
public CreateInfoContactController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    infoContact = (InfoContact__c)stdController.getRecord();
    wraps = new List<Wrapper>();

    Map <String, Schema.SObjectField> mapTypes = new Map<String, Schema.SObjectField>(infoContact.getSObjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap());

    for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : this.getInfoContact()) {

        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> lst = mapTypes.get(f.getFieldPath()).getDescribe().getPicklistValues();
        Wrapper w = new Wrapper(f.getLabel(), f.getFieldPath());
        for (Schema.PicklistEntry pe: lst){
            w.values.add(pe.getValue());
        }
        wraps.add(w);

    }

}

public List<Schema.FieldSetMember> getInfoContact() {
    return SObjectType.InfoContact__c.FieldSets.InfoContact.getFields();
}

public class Wrapper{
    public String fieldLabel {get;set;}
    public String fieldName {get;set;}
    public List<String> values{get;set;}

    public Wrapper(String fLabel, String fName){
        fieldLabel = fLabel;
        fieldName = fName;
        values = new List<String>();
    }
}

private String setName(String nam){
    String newName = '';

    for (Integer i = 0; i < Integer.valueOf(Label.CountOfZeroInOpportunityName) - nam.length(); i++){

        newName += '0';

    }

    newName = newName + nam;

    return newName;

}

public void setValues(){
    system.debug('nameField '+nameField);
    system.debug('valueField '+valueField);


    infoContact.put(nameField, valueField);

}

public PageReference saveInfoContact(){
    //Id infoTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('GuidedTrail').getRecordTypeId();
    RecordType infoType = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE DeveloperName='GuidedTrail'];
    List<Opportunity> opps = [Select id from Opportunity where recordTypeId=:infoType.id];

    String s = setName(String.valueOf(opps.size()));

    //Datetime myD = Datetime.now();

    //String myDate = myD.format('dd:mm:yy'); 

    String nameOpp = 'GT-'+s;

    insert infoContact;
    Opportunity op = new Opportunity(name = nameOpp, closeDate = Date.today(), infoContactId__c = infoContact.Id, recordTypeId = infoType.id, StageName = 'test');
    insert op;

    PageReference infoContactPage = new ApexPages.StandardController(infoContact).view();
    infoContactPage.setRedirect(true);
    return infoContactPage;
}

}
```

Comment: can you post your controller, do you have a wrapper inside a wrapper?

Comment: From the initial scan you have TWO `rerender` and nothing in the controller resets the wrap (even so no rerender). Do you have any JS on the page that is changing the status / properties of the buttons? what is in the hidden block?

Comment: Thank you, was trying to get around the problem and placed two rerenders(by mistake). But they don't affect behavior of the buttons. Hidden block is needed to pass parameter on commandButton click -  [apex:param doesn't support commandbutton](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_param.htm) and rerendering a hidden block is one of the workarounds,  [described there](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/03/04/passing-parameters-with-a-commandbutton/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insted of using commandButtons, decided to use **selectRadio** with custom styles:

```
<style type="text/css">

input[type=radio] {
    display:none;
  }

  input[type=radio] + label {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:-2px;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#fff),to(#e6e6e6));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    border-bottom-color: #b3b3b3;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff',endColorstr='#ffe6e6e6',GradientType=0);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  }

  input[type=radio]:checked + label {
       background-image: none;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
      background-color:#e0e0e0;
  }
</style>
```

and vf page:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!wraps}" var="w">

          <div class="slds-container--center slds-container--small slds-align--absolute-center">
             <div class="slds-form-element__label slds-text-heading--medium slds-m-around--medium"> 
               {!w.fieldLabel}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slds-container--center slds-container--small slds-align--absolute-center">
            <div class="slds-form-element">
              <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                <apex:selectRadio value="{!w.fieldValue}">

                  <apex:selectOptions value="{!w.values}"/>
                </apex:selectRadio >

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </apex:repeat>
```

Works perfectly for me.